# System of $3$ (nonlinear) equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

> Let $x,y,z$ be real numbers. Solve the following system:
>   $$\left\{\begin{matrix} x^{100}+\frac {1}{x^{100}}=y^{2018}+1
> \\ y^{1918}+\frac {1}{y^{1918}}=z^{2018}+1
> \\ z^{100}+\frac {1}{z^{100}}=x^{2018}+1
> \end{matrix}\right.$$

What I have tried is to consider two cases:
 $x\geq y \geq z\geq 1$  and then prove that $x=y=z=1$. And the other case $x \leq y \leq z \leq -1$ and then prove $x=y=z=-1$. But I can't find a link between the variables. Any ideea or help I would greatfully appreciate.

Comment: Source of this question, please?

Comment: National math magazine Romania

Comment: Are you supposed to post their problems to websites?

Comment: What can I do if I cannot find the answer? Not ask. I'm asking for help, not for the hole prove.